# Notes app that saves all notes in one encrypted file (open source)

Tags: windows, linux, note-taking

I'm looking for a encrypted notes app.
It sould save the notes like KeePass, in a encrypted database file. I want decide where to save it. Not automatically in someone's cloud. Does not necessarily need an mobile app.

For Windows and Linux/Debian.

Comment: The title says open source, but you didn’t add the [tag:open-source] tag. Before you do, consider if the [tag:gratis] tag would be more appropriate, as it will attract more answer, especially for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/) is a general purpose single file local web application that can, among other things, be used for note taking.

Files can be encrypted with a password, and it can run on any platform with a modern web browser.

[Treeline](http://treeline.bellz.org/) is also a versatile mini database/outliner application that can save structured data as a password protected xml file.

[Cherry Tree](https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree) can also encrypt a single notes file. Have in mind that while in use, an unencrypted working version is kept in the temp folder, it is eliminated upon closing the document. If the application closed unexpectedly, crashes or force quits an unsecured copy of data may be left behind.